# In WPF, how can I get the RowDefinition object from the UIElement that belongs to it?

Tags: wpf, grid, uielement, rowdefinition

Take the following window layout for example: 
There is a `Grid` element defined. It has 3 rows. Each row has one Button element. How do I get the `RowDefinition` object of the Button it belongs to? Thanks.

NOTE: By calling `Grid.GetRow(Button element)`, I am getting the `Grid.Row` property of that Button element. I do not need that - instead I need the actual `RowDefinition` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
int rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(myButton);

RowDefinition rowDef = myGrid.RowDefinitions[rowIndex];
```

Or in one line:

```
RowDefinition rowDef = myGrid.RowDefinitions[Grid.GetRow(myButton)];
```