# Switch the button content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I am in need of help to switch the content of two buttons

what I have done so far is to check if the buttons are neighbours.

```
private int row = 4;
private int col = 4;

public MainWindow()
{

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button cmd = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(cmd.Tag.ToString());
    string txt = cmd.Tag.ToString();
    int r = int.Parse("" + txt[0]);
    int c = int.Parse("" + txt[1]);
    if (Math.Abs(r - row) + Math.Abs(c - col) == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(r + "  " + c);
    }
```

And my buttons in my XAML file is like this

```
<Button Tag="00" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="Button_Click">A</Button>
<Button Tag="01" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click">B</Button>
```

and the Challenge is to switch the content (A and B)

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Somewhere a little WPF kitten died. Please check out Karel's answer. Switching the Button Models should then be a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

1. do not use WinForms event handling like `Button_Click` method.
2. use binding for button content
3. look at the commands
4. look at the MVVM approach

Answer (score 0):

Just use a temporary variable to hold one of the strings.

```
string tmp = Button1.Text;
Button1.Text = Button2.Text;
Button2.Text = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the generic eventhandler name. You need to store the button you want to move to in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

I used nine Buttons:

```
        <Button Tag="00" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click">A</Button>
        <Button Tag="01" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn2" Click="btn1_Click">B</Button>
        <Button Tag="02" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn3" Click="btn1_Click">C</Button>
        <Button Tag="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn4" Click="btn1_Click">D</Button>
        <Button Tag="11" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn5" Click="btn1_Click">E</Button>
        <Button Tag="12" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn6" Click="btn1_Click">F</Button>
        <Button Tag="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn7" Click="btn1_Click">G</Button>
        <Button Tag="21" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn8" Click="btn1_Click">H</Button>
        <Button Tag="22" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="15,21,13,23" Name="btn9" Click="btn1_Click">I</Button>
```

and This Method to get the Button from the Grid and Change Values:

```
private int row = 2;
    private int col = 2;

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        Button cmd = (Button)sender;
        string txt = cmd.Tag.ToString();
        int r = int.Parse("" + txt[0]);
        int c = int.Parse("" + txt[1]);
        if (Math.Abs(r - row) + Math.Abs(c - col) == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(r + "  " + c);
            Button nearButton = grd1.Children.Cast<Button>().First(e => Grid.GetRow(e) == row && Grid.GetColumn(e) == col);
            Object tmp = nearButton.Content;
            nearButton.Content = cmd.Content;
            cmd.Content = tmp;
        }
    }
```

In my Example the two Buttons next to the specified change their value with it, hope that is what you intended.

(Getting an Item from a Grid via the X and Y is stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511722/how-to-programmatically-access-control-in-wpf-grid-by-row-and-column-index))