# Getting values from dynamically generated controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I am generating wpf form dynamically. All the controls are generated dynamically as follows

A sample code snippet

```
String tbname = name;
TextBlock txtBlock1 = new TextBlock();
txtBlock1.Text = tbname;

Grid.SetRow(txtBlock1, count);
Grid.SetColumn(txtBlock1, icount);
SampleGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock1);
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Text = ptiAttribute.description;
txtBox.Name = tbname.Replace(" ", "");
DynamicGrid.RegisterName(txtBox.Name, txtBox);
Grid.SetRow(txtBox, count);
Grid.SetColumn(txtBox, icount+1);
SampleGrid.Children.Add(txtBox);
```

Attaching a button click event as follows

```
var Button = CreateButton("Save", 15, 3);
Button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
SampleGrid.Children.Add(Button);
```

I would like to get all the control values (For example: The above text box has value Book), I have to get it after button click. I am not only having text box. I have combo box, date picker too. I don't know which name is registered (RegisterName). Every thing dynamic.

```
private static void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   # How  to get dynamic values here (text bx value, date picker value, combo box value)
}
```

Simply, how to get values from dynamically generated controls. I have gone through a lot of **Visual tree** links but I don't know how it works on button click.

Any simple code snippet will help me to move ahead. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the Button object in the event handler?

Comment: @someone: No, he's trying to get all other controls there

Comment: No. I need values from text box, date picker and combo box

Comment: @Tim - Yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not used to WPF but try this approach(inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511722/how-to-programmatically-access-control-in-wpf-grid-by-row-and-column-index)):

```
private static void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)sender; 
   int row = Grid.GetRow(btn);
   TextBox txtBox = SampleGrid.Children
      .OfType<TextBox>()
      .First(txt => txt.Name == name && Grid.GetRow(txt) == row);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the immediate response. I ll check and update

Comment: The method does not know SampleGrid. This is underlined in my VS and the name is static it seems.

Comment: @Jefferson: well, you have used `SampleGrid` and the `name` variable in your code. So you know where it is

Comment: @EdPlunkett - DataGrid is the original name but it found in another method, button_click does not know that

Comment: @EdPlunkett: what means it's found in another method? Is the button-click handler in the same class? Why you can't access the datagrid then?